# Como recarregar o conteudo de um popup (modal)

Tags: php, javascript, crud, popup

Tenho um formulario que um dos botoes quando se clica abre um popup (modal). Dentro desse popup eu tenho um crud simples de inserir, editar e excluir pessoas. Quando clico em uma dessas opções, um novo formulario se abre numa nova guia. Queria saber como faço pra depois de salvar/editar/excluir nessa guia, eu fechar essa aba e atualizar a minha modal que tava aberta na pagina anterior. Eu ja consegui fazer a aba se fechar, mas nao consigo atualizar o popup, ou entao fazer ele reabrir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o window.opener e re-atribuir o próprio location.href. Isso irá funcionar como um re-load da página que a abriu:

```
<script>
    window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
</script>
```